# Using conditional lambda statements with a foreach Action on a list

Tags: c#, lambda

Why Cant I do something like this?

If I have a `List<String> myList` populated with items, I want to be able to act on each member in a conditional way like so:

```
myList.ForEach(a => { if (a.Trim().Length == 0) a = "0.0"; })
```

But this will not compile. Im guessing its something to do with missing a return value?

Im trying to prepare a list of strings for conversion to doubles, and I want the empty items to show '0.0' so I can just convert the whole list in one go.

Comment: I highly recommend you to visit www.lambdaexpression.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ForEach is not mutable, it doesn't change the data structure in any way.

You can either:

1. Handle the loop yourself, with an index
2. Produce a new list, using .Select and .ToList (provided you're using .NET 3.5)

Example of #1:

```
for (Int32 index = 0; index < myList.Count; index++)
    if (myList[index].Trim().Length == 0)
        myList[index] = "0.0";
```

With .NET 3.5 and Linq:

```
myList = (from a in myList
          select (a.Trim().Length == 0) ? "0.0" : a).ToList();
```

With .NET 3.5, not using the Linq-syntax, but using the Linq-code:

```
myList = myList.Select(a => (a.Trim().Length == 0) ? "0.0" : a).ToList();
```

---

**Edit**: If you want to produce a new list of doubles, you can also do that in one go using Linq:

```
List<Double> myDoubleList =
    (from a in myList
     select (a.Trim().Length == 0 ? "0" : a) into d
     select Double.Parse(d)).ToList();
```

Note that using "0.0" instead of just "0" relies on the decimal point being the full stop character. On my system it isn't, so I replaced it with just "0", but a more appropriate way would be to change the call to Double.Parse to take an explicit numeric formatting, like this:

```
List<Double> myDoubleList =
    (from a in myList
     select (a.Trim().Length == 0 ? "0.0" : a) into d
     select Double.Parse(d, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hmmm ok , is there any extension method that will allow you to act on each item in the list?

Comment: Not that I know of, and I doubt it, most of the Linq-methods are built in a functional style, which disallows changing the input in any way.

Answer (score 4):

What you possibly want is:

```
public static void MutateEach(this IList<T> list, Func<T, T> mutator)
{
    int count = list.Count;
    for (int n = 0; n < count; n++)
        list[n] = mutator(list[n]);
}
```

Which would allow:

```
myList.MutateEach(a => (a.Trim().Length == 0) ? "0.0" : a);
```

Just put the `MutateEach` method in a public static class of your own and make sure you have a using directive that will find it.

Whether it's worth defining something like this depends on how often you'd use it. Note that it has to be an extension on `IList` instead of `IEnumerable`, so we can perform the updates, which makes it less widely applicable.

Comment: You guys are fantastic. I learn something every time I ask a question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

@daniel-earwicker's `MutateEach` Extension solution is a good solution.

---

Though, for returning a new `List`, you have the option to use `List.ConvertAll<TTo>(Converter<TFrom,TTo>(Func<TFrom, TTo>))`, which has been around since .NET 2.0.

It is not **Linq**, or **Lambda**.

```
List<String> nodeStringList = new List<String>(new String[] { "", "0.5 ", " 1.1"}); 

nodeStringList = nodeStringList.ConvertAll<String>((c) => (c.Value.Trim().Length != 0) ? c.Value.Trim() : "0.0");
```

---

[MSDN Reference - List.ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.85).aspx#Y100)